# How to return a value from and onclick event in a rock paper scissors simulation?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a rock,paper, scissors program where a user can press one of three images that appear on the webpage(rock, paper or scissors).

When the user clicks on one of these images, it changes an image to the left of these 3 to a hand in the shape of one of the three choices. Also, a picture to the right of the user's image also changes randomly(computer controlled).

When these two images match, there is a tie. When the image on the left beats the image on the right, there is a win(rock beats paper). When the image on the left beats image on the right, there is a loss.

These three outcomes are written below the set of images in the form of

> "Wins: # Ties: # Losses: #"

The hashtags represent numbers that start at 0 change as the game progresses and **resets to 0** when the page is refreshed.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to return a value to the HTML file from JavaScript when the user interacts.

I thought an `if` statement would do the trick, however the value on my webpage isn't changing, it remains blank.

Here's my HTML

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="center">
        <!--results will change when user interacts-->
        <b>
            <span id="Wins">Wins:&nbsp;</span> 
            <span id="Losses">Losses:&nbsp;</span> 
            <span id="Ties">Ties:&nbsp;</span>
        </b>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and here's the first part of 3 from my javaScript

```
var counter = {win: 0, tie: 0, loss: 0}

function clickRock() {
    var computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

    img = document.getElementById("change1");
    img.src = "leftRockHand.jpg"; //if user presses the rock, the rock hand is displayed
    img = document.getElementById("change2"); 

    //randomly picks a picture of a hand for the computer
    switch(computerChoice){ 
      case 0:
        img.src = "rightRockHand.jpg";
        break;
      case 1:
        img.src = "rightPaperHand.jpg";
        break;
      case 2:
        img.src = "rightScissorHand.jpg";
        break;
    }

    Wins.innerHTML = rockWin;

    if (computerChoice === "rightRockHand.jpg") {
        rockWin + 1;
    }

    return rockWin;
}
```

Comment: Please create a `fiddle` or other demo link so we can see it in action.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cr_harrison14/rya66w3h/1/#update here is a fiddle of the code

Comment: I recommend you upload your images to imgur.com so you can reference the images directly for easier viewing (because they are broken images in the JSFiddle) and so you don't have to host them yourself.

Comment: How do I upload imgur images to fiddler? Sorry this is my first time using the website. Here is a link to the imgur album if that helps. http://imgur.com/a/qaXD0

Comment: I tried the code ochi wrote and it didn't change the value on the webpage, I assume because there is some wrong with my html. I've changed it a bit since the first post but can't get it working.                 <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="center"><b>Wins: <span id="Wins">0</span>&nbsp; <span id="Losses">Losses: 0&nbsp;</span> <span id="Ties">Ties: 0&nbsp;</span>  </b></td> <!--results will change when user interacts--></tr>

Answer (score 3):

Multiple issues:

1. Paper beats rock
2. Use `rockwin += 1` instead of `rockwin + 1`
3. You should set `rockwin` before you set the wins span based off of rockwin
4. You didn't set `Wins` to the wins span
5. You didn't get the value of `rockwins`

**JS**

```
var counter = {win: 0, tie: 0, loss: 0}

    function clickRock() {
        var computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        img = document.getElementById("change1");
        img.src = "leftRockHand.jpg"; //if user presses the rock, the rock hand is displayed
        img = document.getElementById("change2"); 
        switch(computerChoice){ //randomly picks a picture of a hand for the computer
        case 0:
            img.src = "rightRockHand.jpg";
        break;
        case 1:
            img.src = "rightPaperHand.jpg";
        break;
        case 2:
            img.src = "rightScissorHand.jpg";
        break;
        }
        var Wins=document.getElementById('Wins');
        var rockwin = Wins.innerHTML;
        if (computerChoice === "rightPaperHand.jpg") {
            rockWin += 1;
        }
        Wins.innerHTML = rockWin;
        return rockWin;
    }
```

Comment: I always thought rock beats everything but +1, paper beats rock :)